# Should I use a For - in loop in swift to set field value

Tags: swift

I have created an app with a codeable array in Swift.  I have a boolean field to show which item in my list is the active record.  If I choose another item in my list to make active (true) I would like to mark all other records as false.  I was wondering if using a for-in loop would be the proper way to do this?

I have this code to activate the button but have been told that is not the proper way to do it.

```
   @IBAction func activateButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        activateButton.isSelected = !activateButton.isSelected
        updateSaveButtonState()
   }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A for-loop would be the most naive (simple) way to do this, but not the most performant as the number of button increases (you're bound by O(n) time).

If one and only one button can be active at a time then you're better off using another variable to reference the currently active button. Your code would instead look like this:

```
private weak var activeButton: UIButton?

@IBAction func activateButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    activeButton?.isSelected = false
    sender.isSelected = true
    activeButton = sender
}
```

This ensures O(1) time.

If you want multiple buttons active at once, you can use an array of active buttons, which you'd loop over to deactivate. In that case, you still have a worst case O(n) time complexity, but you're almost always going to be looping over a smaller subset of the buttons.

Comment: could be also completely done inside `didSet`, using `oldValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a `for in` loop would be perfect for this. You could set all the buttons selection status to `false` and then set the one you just activated to `true`.

```
for button in buttons {
    button.isSelected = false
}
activateButton.isSelected = true
```

---

Or you could check in the loop if the button being tapped is the one that in the loop.

```
for button in buttons {
    button.isSelected = button == activateButton
}
```

Comment: I think using first(where:) might be faster since it's a single selection

Comment: @zombie `first(where:)` has no applicability here. Every button needs to be updated.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Will looping through the buttons after setting one to true set all of the other records in the array to false?  I want to make sure only one record is set to true at all times.

Comment: Yeah, no. This is an X/Y problem. The question is "How do I manage an array of Bools so I can have one and only one item selected. The answer is "Don't use an array of bools. Use a variable to keep track of the selected item, and when you change selected items, deselect the old one and select the new one." See Nima's answer for a much better solution.

Comment: My button is set to cycle from true to false when I click it and then is saved to a record in an array with one field that is a string and the other as a bool.  Nima's code will only set the button to true on the current record.  The only way I can see doing it is to do it is loop through all of the records and set them to false and then set the current record to true.